# Defining a function with argument of type System.Array in ASMX C# web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, system.array

I am getting the following error 
`You must implement a default accessor on System.Array because it inherits from ICollection`

Following is my source code,

```
 public string extractOutput(ref System.Array data)
    {
       obj.extractOuput(ref data);
    }
```

I will access this webservice from the client as,

```
System.Array bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("path_to_file");
clientObj.extractOutput(ref bytes);
```

Comment: Array should be byte []

Answer (score 1):

I believe this means that the type of the object needs to be known at compile time in order to use the default accessor (which basically means the ability to access an item in the array). Usually due to serialization. Try using an `ArrayList<type>` or just a `List<type>` instead.

```
public string extractOutput(ref ArrayList<SomeType> data)
{
   ...
}
```

or...

```
public string extractOutput(ref List<SomeType> data)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: It basically calls a function from the dll added as reference to the project. Hence am getting No matching overloaded function available.

Comment: It should be byte [] not Array